# Creating an object and running a method

Tags: java, android, class

Create an object and run a method:
It compiles just fine but the App crashes instantly upon launch :(
I implemented the interface and all..
What's going on?

MainActivity.java

---

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public interface MyInterfcae {
    void test0();
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


     Test t = new Test();

     t.test0();




}
```

---

Test.java

---

```
public class Test extends MainActivity implements MainActivity.MyInterfcae {

public Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button0);
@Override
public void test0(){



    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Implemented!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

            toast.show();

        }
    });




}
```

---

It compiles just fine but the App crashes instantly upon launch :(
I implemented the interface and all..
What's going on?

Comment: `public class Test extends MainActivity` ??? `Test t = new Test();` ???????

Comment: What's wrong? "Test t = new Test();" Isn't that how an object is created?

Comment: Well not Activities of the Android Framework!

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, it worked for the test but not implementing it on multiple activities. Debug: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo" :( Can you help me out?

Comment: There are a bunch of lines under that that specify the exact line where the crash happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button0);
```

This link gives an error. You haven't inflated the layout file related to this activity and you are trying to access button0. So, in order to resolve this error pass the layout file instance in the method and then do findViewById() using that instance.

Do like this:-

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    public interface MyInterfcae
    {
        void test0(Context context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Test t = new Test();
        t.test0(this);
    }
}
```

Test.java

```
public class Test extends MainActivity implements MainActivity.MyInterfcae
{
    Context context;

    @Override
    public void test0(final Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;

        Button b = (Button) ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.button0);

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Implemented!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();

            }
        });


    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: I tried passing "public Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button0);" inside the method and it still crashing

Comment: You can't pass that. You have to pass context. I have updated the answer. Plz look @xmarcioras